# fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, deprecated, facebook-graph-api-v2.1

I get an error message as

> fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher

And facebook graph has a minimum version of 2.1.
So does this mean that fql is history now.

I am trying the following FQL

```
SELECT attachment FROM stream WHERE post_id = "id"
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The FQL and REST APIs are no longer available in v2.1

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1

v2.0 is "Unavailable as of August 7, 2016" according to the changelog, so FQL does not work anymore. You will have to use the Graph API instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/post

Comment: i am trying to get larger images for the posts i get via graph API. I used FQL for doing so. Now how can i do so. any suggestions?

Comment: Got it. using graph api /post_id/?fields=full_picture. Thanks anyways :-)